# Facebook Graph API - diferentes valores para ações entre Facebook e API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou usando a API do Facebook (Ads Insights) para retornar as ações de campanhas. Porém o valor retornado pela API não bate com qualquer valor mostrado na publicação do próprio Facebook

**Minha Solicitação em JavaScript**

```
var d = new FormData();
d.append("access_token", MEU_TOKEN);
d.append("fields", "actions");
d.append("date_preset", "lifetime"); // I want lifetime data

return await (await fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/" + campaignid + "/insights", {
    method: "post",
    body: d
})).json();
```

Essa solicitação é assíncrona, após a resposta eu consulto os dados pela seguinte URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/REPORT_RUN_ID/insights?access_token=MEU_TOKEN

**Este é o JSON retornado pela API**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "actions": [
                {
                    "action_type": "comment",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "like",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "photo_view",
                    "value": "30"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "post",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "link_click",
                    "value": "7"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "page_engagement",
                    "value": "249"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "post_engagement",
                    "value": "245"
                },
                {
                    "action_type": "post_reaction",
                    "value": "205"
                }
            ],
            "date_start": "2018-07-09",
            "date_stop": "2018-07-15",
            "ad_id": null // removed
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
        }
    },
    "__fb_trace_id__": null // removed
}
```

Esta é a visualização da postagem pelo administrador da conta e campanha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso saber:

- Por que o Facebook me retorna o campo `post_reaction` com **205** sendo que na página do Facebook eu tenho **150** ou **160** reações? Essa divergência ocorre com outros campos também.

Notas

> - Não estou usando SDK alguma
> - Meu grupo de anúncios possui somente **UM** anúncio e somente **UMA** campanha (esta que estou realizando solicitações)
> - A solicitação e a campanha foram visualizadas ao mesmo tempo, e a campanha é antiga o suficiente (10 de Julho) para que qualquer cache seja atualizado; a campanha também está inativa faz alguns dias
> - Eu sei que o Gerenciador de Anúncios traz alguns valores da API e que lá os valores são exatamente os mesmos, mas nesse caso o Gerenciador não traz os likes, comments ou post_reactions, somente "Total de Ações", um campo que será removido (o próprio gerenciador de Anúncios usa a versão 2.11)
> - Aceito respostas em diferentes linguagens de programação, SDKs ou apenas URL's get ou post, pois o meu problema é sobre entender como funciona esta consulta (ou se estou fazendo algo errado) e não sobre como implementar especificamente.

Comment: Acho bem provável que os dados de interface do facebook sejam atrasados, assim como no Youtube e outras mais. Aguarda um pouco ou ver uma postagem que há tempos ninguém olha e compara os resultados.

Comment: @EdesonBizerril a postagem é de 10 de Julho, comparei já com outras 2~3 campanhas anteriores e a divergência acontece também

Answer (score 0):

O post é antigo, mas muitos ainda tem dúvida neste quesito. Os dados estão diferentes por que na requisição a grahp api, você está puxando os dados da campanha. E você está comparando com a publicação, que tem dados orgânicos contabilizados também.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).